# abstract base class calling parent's pure virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-functions

A coworker asked me today about code which looks somewhat like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class IBase {
public:
    virtual ~IBase() {}

public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Base : public IBase<T> {
public:
    virtual void bar() {
        foo(); // compiler error
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<int> {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.bar();
}
```

At first he was getting a compiler error saying that "`foo()`" was not found. OK, so he tried to change it to `IBase<T>::foo();`. While that compiled, it resulting in a linker error. So immediately, I recalled that I've seen this type of problem before and suggesting that he write `this->foo();` instead. Viola! problem solved!

Then he asked me **why didn't plain `foo();` work**? **Isn't `this->x();` essentially the same as `x();`**? Honestly, I have no idea, but he piqued my interest. So here we are:

In summary:

```
virtual void bar() {
    this->foo();       // works
    //IBase<T>::foo(); // linker error
    //foo();           // compiler error
}
```

The question is **why is `this->` required. And why won't the other options work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the base class member is a *dependent name* - its meaning depends on the template parameter, and so isn't known until the template is instantiated. The name isn't looked up in the generic `IBase` template, since that might be specialised to give it a different meaning before instantiation.

Qualifying it with `IBase<T>::` calls the base-class function non-virtually; that's generally not what you want, especially if (as here) it's a pure virtual function with no implementation. Hence the linker error when you tried that.

Qualifying it with `this->` tells the compiler that it's a member, and any further checking is deferred until the template is instantiated. The function is still called virtually.

Comment: But `Base::` also suppresses virtual call semantics, which is why there's a linker error.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Good point, I didn't think that through properly.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are the compiler. You have just been reading through and compiling the code and now you have reached the `bar` function. In this function, you see that there is an attempt to do `foo()`. At this point, do you know what `foo` is? You don't. It could come from the base class, but you can't possibly know, because you don't know what `T` is yet. It's certainly possible that there might be a specialization of `IBase` for which `foo` is something else entirely.

When you stick `this->` before the function call, it causes the compiler to treat it as a dependent name. That means the compiler will say "Okay, this depends on the type of `this`, which I do not know yet. I'll wait until later, when I know how the class is being instantiated, before I look for `foo`."

`IBase<T>::foo();` gives a linker error because there simply is no definition for `foo` in `IBase<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class IBase {
public:
  virtual ~IBase() {}

public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

int foo() { std::cout << "hello!\n"; }
template <class T>
class Base : public IBase<T> {
public:
  virtual void bar() {
    foo(); // which foo?!
  }
};
template <>
class IBase<int> {
public:
  virtual ~IBase() {}
//virtual void foo() = 0; -- no foo()!
};

class Derived : public Base<int> {
public:
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.bar();
}
```

The above illustrates why C++ does not allow members of dependent type parents to be implicitly found.

When you call `foo()` in `Base`, which `foo()` should be called?  The one in `IBase<T>` or the free function `foo()`?

Either we put the decision off until later, or we go with the free function `foo()`.

If we only go with the free function `foo()` if one is visible, then subtle changes in `#include` order can massively change what your program does.  So if it should call the free function `foo()`, it must error if one is not found, or we are completely screwed.

If we defer the decision until later, it means less of the `template` can be parsed and understood until a later date.  This moves more errors to the point of instantiation.  It also results in some surprising behavior, like in the above case, where someone might think "I'm calling the method `foo()`", but actually ends up calling the free function `foo()` with no diagnostic.